# Thickbox no longer working on front end, did code change in WP3.3 beta 3?

Tags: thickbox

Prior to the 3.3 beta 3 I used thickbox on the front end with the below script. Since beta 3 the lightbox has stopped working. Is there an error in my code or did the function change?

```
function add_themescript(){
    if(!is_admin()){
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox',null,array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox.css', '/'.WPINC.'/js/thickbox/thickbox.css', null, '1.0');
    }

}
add_action('init','add_themescript');
```

Comment: Is the thickbox script being included in the markup on the frontend?

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: Yes, the css and the js are included. No errors are evident. It just does not work.

Comment: Here is [code that works in 3.3](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/adding-jquery-and-thickbox-to-wordpress-theme/41087#41087).

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly related to an issue in Wordpress regarding cache that has just been fixed within the last hour:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/19318

Here's the Trac ticket:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19240

Clearing your cache may help in the meantime before beta 4/RC1

Comment: Thanks Tom. Clearing the cache didn't help but hopefully the patch will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

WP 3.3 uses jQuery 1.7. It's possible that the thickbox script doesn't work with 1.7. I know some other scripts, such as the popular Nivo Slider, have had problems with it already.

Comment: but the built in media uploader works with that version of jQuery and ThickBox

Comment: Good call there.