# Adding jquery and thickbox to WordPress theme

Tags: jquery, gallery, wp-enqueue-script, links, thickbox

I would like to add thickbox for the template which I develop to WordPress. At this time I'm trying with a clean template that have only `header.php`, `footer.php`,`index.php`, and `functions.php`.

I've included the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` into `header.php` and the `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` into `footer.php`.

I've included the `wp_head` like this:

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
wp_head();
?>
```

I've changed the gallery link classes to thickbox with this code in `functions.php`

```
<?php add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'sant_prettyadd');

function sant_prettyadd ($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<a/","<a class=\"thickbox[slides]\"",$content,1);
    return $content;
}
?>
```

When I'm clicking on to a gallery image it should open with thickbox but it opens the imagefile only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function (in your functions.php file) to call the relevant scripts you need. It allows for both built-in libraries and to add any custom that you're including in your theme.

Comment: Okay I enquaue the scripts from functions. Do I do right if just include the enquaue or should I use init?

Comment: If you're loading multiple, or using conditionals (i.e. only load script X on single posts and script Y on the home page) than an init is a better bet. But either way you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much it's succesfull .. I'm lucky with ya!

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is a simple call in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_thickbox' );
```

That’s it. WordPress will now enqueue jQuery and the thickbox script. By default, linked images aren’t thickboxy yet. You need to:

1. Add a class `thickbox` to the links manually/per PHP, or
2. Use a second script to add these classes automagically.

Sample code for `footer.php`:

```
<script>
jQuery('a img.size-medium').parent().addClass('thickbox').attr('rel', 'page');
</script>
<?php
wp_footer();
```

This code adds the class `thickbox` to all links around medium sized images, and it groups these links to enable the next/prev navigation links.

Now you get a basic thickbox with translated navigation links:

[image]

Since this is a script managed by the core it is *not* keyboard user friendly: The arrow keys don’t do anything. If you need a more usable solution – take a plugin.

Another note: Thickbox may be removed sooner or later from the core. See [Ticket 10955](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10955).

Answer (score -1):

Hi can any one help me to resolve my problem::

Here it my code

```
<a href="'. site_url("wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=user_avatar_add_photo&step=1&uid="). $myUID . '&TB_iframe=true&width=720&height=450" title="Upload and Crop an Image to be Displayed" >' . ( 'Update Picture','wp-members' ) . '</a>
```

this piece of code i'm trying to use in Wp-admin profile it is working fine but.. there is a problem... i.e while I try to chance the user avatar from front end TB_ifram is not popping up... it is spreading to whole webpage...

here it's image: [image]
here i need to popup the TB_Ifram content frame from the front end... plz give me suggestion that would be great to you..

regards

Comment: Welcome to WordPress SE. If you have a question, please start a [new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) rather than posting it as an answer on another question. Thanks!