# How can I make all gallery images to open in a new window?

Tags: images, shortcode, gallery

How can I make all gallery images to open the high resolution image in a new window?

Comment: Do you mean a [Thickbox](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/adding-jquery-and-thickbox-to-wordpress-theme/41087#41087)? Please improve your question.

Comment: not a thickbox, I want when a user clicks on a photo in a gallery image from a post to open a new window to display the full size photo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*(Update 04.05.2012: Include captions)*

Let's start with a solution …

There is no filter especially for gallery image links. There is also no filter for the gallery shortcode output. So we have to fake one:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_50911_replace_img_shortcodes' );

/**
 * Replace the default shortcode handlers.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_50911_replace_img_shortcodes()
{
    remove_shortcode( 'gallery', 'gallery_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'wpse_50911_gallery_shortcode' );

    remove_shortcode( 'caption', 'img_caption_shortcode' );
    remove_shortcode( 'wp_caption', 'img_caption_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'caption', 'wpse_50911_caption_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'wp_caption', 'wpse_50911_caption_shortcode' );
}
```

What it does: It replaces the default shortcode handlers for `[gallery]`, `[caption]` and `[wp_caption]`. Now we have to write the replacement functions. That's actually pretty easy because we let WordPress do (almost) all the work:

```
/**
 * Add the new attribute to the gallery.
 *
 * @param  array $attr Shortcode attributes
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_50911_gallery_shortcode( $attr )
{
    // Let WordPress create the regular gallery …
    $gallery = gallery_shortcode( $attr );
    // … and add the target attribute to all links.
    $gallery = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', $gallery );

    return $gallery;
}

/**
 * Add the new attribute to the caption.
 *
 * @param  array  $attr    Shortcode attributes
 * @param  string $content Caption text
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_50911_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content = NULL )
{
    $caption = img_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content );
    $caption = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', $caption );
    return $caption;
}
```

What it does: It's delegating the shortcode work to the native WordPress functions. Then it takes the output and inserts the attribute `target="_blank"`. And then it returns the output to the page.

Done. When you insert a gallery or a caption make sure the links point to the file URI, not to an attachment page.

### Caveats

- The new window will break the back button. That's *very* annoying for users of screen readers or some mobile devices.
- Safari mobile once could not open more than seven windows (not sure if this still true) and just refused to open a new one when the limit was reached. A click on such a link may do *nothing*.
- Some users just hate forced new tabs/windows. I'm one of those. :)
- If you use another plugin to change the gallery output it will probably not work anymore.

Do not use this code … unless you are forced with a lot of money to do it.

Comment: Yes, safari still not opening more tabs. Might be that every tab is running his own instance of the mobile browser and memory would be gone after that.

Comment: thanks man ! I will try it.  I need this because I have high resolution images and they can't be displayed in a lightbox. And many users come to download the images so this way they can download more images easily without losing the current page.

Comment: which php file I have to modify?

Comment: Your theme's `functions.php`. You can put it into a plugin too.

Comment: I have added both code snippets to theme functions.php but the images open in the same window.

Comment: You copied the `add_action` call too? I have tested the code – I _know_ it works.

Comment: yes, I also included add_action

Comment: Look at the HTML source: is the attribute present there? May be a browser setting.

Comment: target blank is not in the html page

Comment: You _did_ use the `[gallery]` shortcode? I have no idea what went wrong then. It works for me. :/

Comment: this is how my post source html looks in wordpress post editor.

Comment: Grunge Concrete Wall Texture Background

[caption id="attachment_382" align="alignnone" width="500" caption="High Resolution 4096 x 2731 pixels, Large JPG image: 6 MB"]<a href="http://paper-backgrounds.com/grunge-concrete-wall-texture/grunge-concrete-wall-texture/" rel="attachment wp-att-382"><img class="size-medium wp-image-382" title="grunge-concrete-wall-texture" src="http://paper-backgrounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/grunge-concrete-wall-texture-500x333.jpg" alt="Grunge Concrete Wall Texture" width="500" height="333" /></a>[/caption]

Comment: That's not a gallery, it's a simple captioned image.

Comment: but I used the Add Media link when I have inserted the photos..., and I how can I add target _blank to captioned images too ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3326/discussion-between-mario-m-and-toscho)

Comment: See the update: I included caption shortcodes too.

Answer (score 2):

*Late answer*

Here's a slightly "improved/shortened" version of @toscho code

### Plugin

Not that I'm a big fan of that idea, I just like the `links_add_target()` function.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: (#50911) Open gallery img in new window/tab */

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse50911_replace_img_shortcodes' );
function wpse50911_replace_img_shortcodes()
{
    remove_shortcode( 'gallery', 'gallery_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'wpse50911_gallery_shortcode' );

    remove_shortcode( 'caption', 'img_caption_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'caption', 'wpse50911_caption_shortcode' );

    remove_shortcode( 'wp_caption', 'img_caption_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'wp_caption', 'wpse50911_caption_shortcode' );
}
function wpse50911_gallery_shortcode( $attr )
{
    return links_add_target( gallery_shortcode( $attr ) );
}
function wpse50911_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content = null)
{
    return img_caption_shortcode( $attr, links_add_target( $content ) );
}
```

Comment: +1 for finding a usage for the `links_add_target()` core function ;-)