# add_filter and changing output captions of image gallery

Tags: filters, shortcode, gallery

I'd like to change only one output of native WP Gallery (in media.php)

On Smashing Magazine ([link](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/26/better-image-management-practices-with-wordpress)) author advises to change whole gallery_shortcode function.
But I wondered if is possible to change only specific output ($captiontag)

I wrote:

```
add_filter( 'captiontag', 'my_captiontag' );

function my_captiontag( $captiontag ) {
 $output .= "
  <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><p>
  " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
  </p></{$captiontag}>";
}
```

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no filter hook called `captiontag`. You can change the value of the caption html tag by specifying the `captiontag` option when inserting the `[gallery]` shortcode.

From the [gallery shortcode codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode):

> **captiontag**
>
> the name of the XHTML tag used to enclose each caption. The default is
>   "dd". For example, to change the gallery markup to use div, span and p
>   tags:
>
> ```
> [gallery itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p"]
> ```

### Update:

The following code will overwrite the default `[gallery]` output. It is basically a copy of the `gallery_shotcode()` function with one modification to display the image title wrapped in `<h3>` tag before the image:

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode', 10, 2);

function my_gallery_shortcode($output, $attr) {
    global $post;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        // Here we add the image title
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                <h3>$attachment->post_title</h3>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for reply. So You're telling me I have to copy whole gallery function like they telling in Smahing Magazine, to have between <dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption"></dd> additional <p></p> tag?

Comment: I am afraid this is true, the only way to change the html markup of the `[gallery]` shortcode is to hook to `gallery_shortcode` filter which is fired at an early point of the `gallery_shortcode` function, meaning that it will _overwrite_ the entire `$output` of that function. Alternatively you can create your own gallery shortcode (eg. `[my_gallery]`) by copying and customizing the default `gallery_shortcode` function and using [`add_shortcode('my_gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) function.

Comment: Ok :-/ If I have to copy whole code, do You know how to display title of image in each thumb from native gallery (like caption is displayed)

Comment: @cachaito lets give it a try. Please see my update.

Comment: It works! Do I see correctly that You added <h3>$attachment->post_title</h3> for displayng thumb title?

Comment: @cachaito: You are correct. Besides I removed the `apply_filter('post_gallery','', $attr)` so we do not get into infinite loop. One more edit: we need to explicitly pass the `$attr` argument so our code wont break.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to copy the `gallery` shortcode. Just set your filter function between the native handler’s output and the final output.

To do that, hijack the shortcode handler, then run a [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) over the output.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_74515_replace_gallery_shortcode' );

/**
 * Replace the default shortcode handlers.
 *
 * @wp-hook after_setup_theme
 * @return  void
 */
function wpse_74515_replace_gallery_shortcode()
{
    // overwrite the native shortcode handler
    add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'wpse_74515_gallery_shortcode' );
}
/**
 * Create a filtered gallery output.
 *
 * @wp-hook gallery
 * @param   array $attr
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_74515_gallery_shortcode( $attr )
{
    // Default value in WordPress.
    $captiontag = 'dd';

    // User value.
    isset ( $attr['captiontag'] ) && $captiontag = $attr['captiontag'];

    // Let WordPress create the regular gallery …
    $gallery = gallery_shortcode( $attr );

    // change the content of the caption
    $gallery = preg_replace_callback(
        '~(<' . $captiontag . '.*>)(.*)(</' . $captiontag . '>)~mUus',
        'wpse_74515_gallery_callback',
        $gallery
    );

    return $gallery;
}
/**
 * Change the result of the regex match from wpse_74515_gallery_shortcode.
 *
 * @param  array $m matches
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_74515_gallery_callback( $m )
{
    return $m[1] . wptexturize( $m[2] ) . $m[3];
}
```

### Similar posts

- [How do i link gallery thumbnails to different url's using the wp native gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53369/73)
- [Using preg_replace to separate gallery from the_content?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53684/73)
- [How can I make all gallery images to open in a new window?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51064/73)