# Change the output for [gallery] shortcode

Tags: images, templates, gallery

I'm sorry if this question was answered here, but I couldn't find it.
Is possible to change the HTML output of [gallery] shortcode (without plugins)?
I would like to show the thumbnails as another appearance. Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74675/73)?

Answer (score 12):

The [source for the gallery shortcode](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php#L672) is in `wp-includes/media.php`. There are a couple of hooks in there that might work for you. Without knowing exactly what you want to do, it is impossible to be more specific.

If that doesn't work then you can [remove the shortcode:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode)

```
remove_shortcode('gallery');
```

And add another gallery shortcode with the alterations you want. [Just copy the function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php#L672) to `functions.php` or to a plugin file, rename it, edit it, and add it back with `add_shortcode('gallery', 'whatever_you_named_your_function');`

Comment: Great! It works for me.

Comment: If this solved the question please mark it as "Accepted". Look for the check mark on the left.