# How to change the output of gallery shortcode

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I would like to **add the media description as a data-attribute** to each image of the gallery. All the other answers favour the solution to copy the whole code from media.php to functions.php and change it there. But isn't there a more intelligent way?

It's way to much **code duplication** in order to change one single line of code!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74675/73)?

Comment: Or [How to customize the output of the gallery shortcode](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-to-customise-the-output-of-the-wp-image-gallery-shortcode-from-a-plugin)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did. It favours the solution, to duplicate the content in functions.php.

Comment: [I see no hook or set of hooks that will do what you want.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L671) I agree it would be nice, and it would be a trivial patch if you wanted to submit such a thing. Maybe it will be included in an upcoming release.

Comment: Thank you guys for your hints. This was exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested: I managed it to add a data attribute to the article thumbnail with following filter:

```
function post_thumbnail_add_data_attribute( $input, $post_image_id ) {
  $caption = wptexturize(get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt);
  $substitute = is_home() ? "<img" : "<img data-description=\"" . $caption . "\"";

  return str_replace("<img", $substitute, $input);
}

add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'post_thumbnail_add_data_attribute', 10, 3 );
```

For the gallery I followed the advice to remove the gallery shortcode...

```
remove_shortcode('gallery');
```

and then to add a customized gallery function to the functions.php...

```
add_shortcode('gallery', 'my_gallery');
```

which contains the tiny customization...

```
// Add the caption of images in a gallery as the name attribute in order to fetch it with jQuery lightbox
$output = str_replace('<img', '<img data-description="' . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . '"', $output);
```