# Display image title and caption inside a single post

Tags: images, title

I want to display image title and caption inside a `<p>` tag in single post in `the_content()` function for every image that has one. So for example if I add gallery, and define title for every image, I want to have above every image it's title displayed, and below every image it's caption displayed, and also for all single images if they have title defined. To visually express it:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Please provide more information about the context of your problem and solutions you have tried yourself. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't even know where to start, that's why I'm asking you.

Comment: The question of supplying more information remains. What is your current situation? What are you trying to accomplish? What research have you done yourself? Are you using a third-party plugin or WordPress' native functionality?

Comment: There, I reformatted a question to make it more understandable. I've done some google-ing, but can't fin proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a few minutes and made the custom code for you.
Copy and paste this in your themes functions.php

```
remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
add_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode_custom');
function gallery_shortcode_custom( $attr ) {
    $post = get_post();

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
        // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
        if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
            $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
        }
        $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
    }

    /**
     * Filter the default gallery shortcode output.
     *
     * If the filtered output isn't empty, it will be used instead of generating
     * the default gallery template.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     * @since 4.2.0 The `$instance` parameter was added.
     *
     * @see gallery_shortcode()
     *
     * @param string $output   The gallery output. Default empty.
     * @param array  $attr     Attributes of the gallery shortcode.
     * @param int    $instance Unique numeric ID of this gallery shortcode instance.
     */
    $output = apply_filters( 'post_gallery', '', $attr, $instance );
    if ( $output != '' ) {
        return $output;
    }

    $html5 = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'gallery' );
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
        'itemtag'    => $html5 ? 'figure'     : 'dl',
        'icontag'    => $html5 ? 'div'        : 'dt',
        'captiontag' => $html5 ? 'figcaption' : 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => '',
        'link'       => ''
    ), $attr, 'gallery' );

    $id = intval( $atts['id'] );

    if ( ! empty( $atts['include'] ) ) {
        $_attachments = get_posts( array( 'include' => $atts['include'], 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $atts['order'], 'orderby' => $atts['orderby'] ) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( ! empty( $atts['exclude'] ) ) {
        $attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $atts['exclude'], 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $atts['order'], 'orderby' => $atts['orderby'] ) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $atts['order'], 'orderby' => $atts['orderby'] ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $attachments ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link( $att_id, $atts['size'], true ) . "\n";
        }
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape( $atts['itemtag'] );
    $captiontag = tag_escape( $atts['captiontag'] );
    $icontag = tag_escape( $atts['icontag'] );
    $valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) ) {
        $itemtag = 'dl';
    }
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) ) {
        $captiontag = 'dd';
    }
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) ) {
        $icontag = 'dt';
    }

    $columns = intval( $atts['columns'] );
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = '';

    /**
     * Filter whether to print default gallery styles.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param bool $print Whether to print default gallery styles.
     *                    Defaults to false if the theme supports HTML5 galleries.
     *                    Otherwise, defaults to true.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', ! $html5 ) ) {
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
        </style>\n\t\t";
    }

    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $atts['size'] );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";

    /**
     * Filter the default gallery shortcode CSS styles.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param string $gallery_style Default CSS styles and opening HTML div container
     *                              for the gallery shortcode output.
     */
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {

        $attr = ( trim( $attachment->post_excerpt ) ) ? array( 'aria-describedby' => "$selector-$id" ) : '';
        if ( ! empty( $atts['link'] ) && 'file' === $atts['link'] ) {
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $atts['size'], false, false, false, $attr );
        } elseif ( ! empty( $atts['link'] ) && 'none' === $atts['link'] ) {
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $atts['size'], false, $attr );
        } else {
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $atts['size'], true, false, false, $attr );
        }
        $image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

        $orientation = '';
        if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) ) {
            $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
        }
        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "<p>$attachment->post_title</p>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
                $image_output
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <p>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </p>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( ! $html5 && $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 ) {
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
        }
    }

    if ( ! $html5 && $columns > 0 && $i % $columns !== 0 ) {
        $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both' />";
    }

    $output .= "
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

If you need to add a custom class to your p tag modify

```
$output .= "<p>$attachment->post_title</p>";
```

and

```
<p>
    " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
</p>";
```

Comment: Great, this is it. How could I do this for single images?

Answer (score -2):

[The answer is here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74515/add-filter-and-changing-output-captions-of-image-gallery) but you will need to edit the code and extract only what you need.

see the last lines of code, the title is wrapped in a h3 tag.

Comment: I downvoted this, the reason is under the rock next to my comment ;-)