# Use full size images in a specific gallery

Tags: shortcode, attachments, gallery, images

Thumbnails are displaying as 100px however the full size is 130px which is what I want.

I want this only in one specific gallery.

Also would like to link each gallery thumbnail image to an external url

Comment: can u add some more infomration.. WHich template you are using?

Comment: Using the default wp gallery with a Genesis child theme. Would also like to space the gallery items equally

Answer (score 1):

The `gallery` shortcode accepts a `size` parameter:

```
[gallery size="full"]
```

This will select the full size image.

For the URLs see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53368/how-do-i-link-gallery-thumbnails-to-different-urls-using-the-wp-native-gallery/53369#53369).

Comment: When inserting the gallery there's No Link To URL under the Gallery Settings even though there is a custom field for this using the code from your link above.

Comment: There's no field for 'Link to' when inserting the gallery so image thumbnails link to media file or attachment Not URL.