# Converting the_content string to an array?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, wpdb

I have created a custom taxonomy, this taxonomy is dedicated to image attachments, when I upload my images `$post->post_content` returns a string like:

```
'[caption id="attachment_98" align="alignnone" width="300"]
  <a href="http://....jpg">
     <img class="size-medium" title="title" src="http://.../wp-content/uploads/2012/10/name.jpg" alt="cardinal2" width="300" height="225" />
  </a>
caption[/caption]'
```

By calling `the_content()` this string becomes an HTML markup, at codex I couldn't find a function that allows me to get the source of the image and caption/description/title of it in a dynamic way, is there a way to output the content without using `the_content()` function? Should I *split* the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `'img_caption_shortcode'`. You get three arguments: an empty string, the attributes (including the attachment id), and the caption content. If you return anything but an empty string WordPress will print your return value instead of its own code.

See `wp-includes/media.php` for details.

Another option: [hijack the caption handlers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51064/73) and create your own output or change the output WordPress builds before it is sent back to the content.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your answer, does this work when I have more than 1 image in my post? is there any other way that I can return title and description of the image too? I am about to create a gallery and I want to json_encode the results.

Comment: See my update, especially the linked answer.