# Add extra class to wp-caption?

Tags: captions

How do you add a new class to the HTML generated when an image with captions is added?

For example, from this:

```
<div id="attachment_xyz" class="wp-caption alignleft"...
```

to this:

```
<div id="attachment_xyz" class="wp-caption alignleft my_new_class"...
```

Adding, in this case, **my_new_class**.

Thanks, Scott

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50911/how-can-i-make-all-gallery-images-to-open-in-a-new-window/51064#51064)? It is almost the same, the second parameter for `str_replace` just has to be changed to `'class="wp-caption '`.

Comment: I wonder why when people try to help they actually get downvoted. Anyways, I still don't understand how to do this - that is, implement the code. Which code exactly would I use? Any help, with good intentions, would be appreciated. Exact code, in kindergarten language :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Adapted from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51064/19726)

Add this code to your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_74735_replace_wp_caption_shortcode' );

/**
 * Replace the default caption shortcode handler.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_74735_replace_wp_caption_shortcode() {
    remove_shortcode( 'caption', 'img_caption_shortcode' );
    remove_shortcode( 'wp_caption', 'img_caption_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'caption', 'wpse_74735_caption_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'wp_caption', 'wpse_74735_caption_shortcode' );
}

/**
 * Add the new class to the caption.
 *
 * @param  array  $attr    Shortcode attributes
 * @param  string $content Caption text
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_74735_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content = NULL )
{
    $caption = img_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content );
    $caption = str_replace( 'class="wp-caption', 'class="wp-caption my_new_class', $caption );
    return $caption;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: Mr. Bunge, I have no idea why people do this. Thanks for trying to help anyways! I still don't know how to do this - I'm one of those graphic designer types just getting into code.

Comment: Install the [Code Snippets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/code-snippets) plugin and, after activation, visit the *Snippets > Add New* menu. Enter the above code into the code textarea and name the snippet. After adding the snippet, visit the *Snippets > Manage Snippets* menu to activate the snippet. Once these steps have been completed there will be an additional class on wp-caption (`my_new_class`).

Comment: If you're designing a theme, you can also create a file in the theme directory called `functions.php` and paste this code into it. (Remember to add a `<?php` tag to the start of the file)

Comment: OK, I know why people downvoted your answer. On the first line of add_action, your newly named function is called 'wpse_74735_replace_img_shortcodes' yet when that function is called it is misnamed as 'wpse_74735_replace_wp_caption_shortcode'. Also I noticed one more thing (you learn SO much from stuff that breaks!). The following line:
    'class="wp-caption my_new_class'
should have a space at the end so the newly named class name doesn't run into the next class as one long class name. But after these fixes, it works. Thanks for making me learn some new stuff by your mistakes :D

Comment: Sorry - I've fixed my answer - the updated code should work. As mentioned, the code was adapted from a different question, and  I should have been more careful porting it over.

Comment: The only thing thing I would do to make it bulletproof is change:

    'class="wp-caption my_new_class'
to
    'class="wp-caption my_new_class '

with the space at the end so it doesn't run into the next class name like this (for example):

    wp-caption my_new_classalignleft

Thanks again!

Comment: It you look at the function again, you will see it replaces class="wp-caption` with `class="wp-caption my_new_class` - no space at the end of either statement. This is to ensure that there is no trailing space at the end on the class list if `wp-caption` was the only class.

Comment: @scottdaris Are you pleased with the new code? If yes, please accept my answer by clicking the green tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress 4.9 you can write your class in the align attribute. I've added full-width to the caption like this.

```
[caption id="attachment_11537" align="aligncenter full-width" width="1170"]<img src="http://pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199-1920x712.png" alt="" width="1170" height="434" class="size-large wp-image-11537" /> Fem øl takk[/caption]
```

The output (with jetpack photon turned on):

```
<figure id="attachment_11537" style="max-width: 1170px" class="wp-caption aligncenter full-width"><img data-attachment-id="11537" data-permalink="http://pappmaskin.no/?attachment_id=11537" data-orig-file="https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?fit=7723%2C2863" data-orig-size="7723,2863" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="Illustrasjon: Morten Skogly" data-image-description="" data-medium-file="https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?fit=640%2C237" data-large-file="https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?fit=1170%2C434" src="https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?resize=1170%2C434" alt="" class="size-large wp-image-11537" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?resize=1920%2C712 1920w, https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?resize=310%2C115 310w, https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?resize=640%2C237 640w, https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?resize=768%2C285 768w, https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?w=2340 2340w, https://i0.wp.com/pappmaskin.no/wp-content/2016/03/IMG_5199.png?w=3510 3510w" sizes="(max-width: 1170px) 100vw, 1170px" width="684" height="254"><figcaption class="wp-caption-text">Fem øl takk</figcaption></figure>
```