# Page template that uses lightbox to display post images

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I have created a page template that displays the featured image for all posts of a certain custom post type.

It uses a normal loop that is querying that specific custom post type. The thumbnails are being displayed using `<?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?>`

I now want to use a lightbox to display the rest of the images in the post. I believe that I need to use `<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src(); ?>`

For some reason I can't quite get my head around it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for joining WPSE. Glad to have you here! If @tosho's answer has solved the issue, please mark it as the correct answer and give him an upvote. This is good protocol and reward for those who spend time to craft answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WordPress’ built-in Thickbox script. Just place the following code somewhere before `wp_footer();`:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 't5_thickbox_jquery' );

function t5_thickbox_jquery()
{
?>
<script>
jQuery( 'a img.size-medium, a img.attachment-thumbnail' )
    .parent()
    .addClass( 'thickbox' )
    .attr( 'rel', 'page' );
</script>
<?php
add_thickbox();
}
```

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/adding-jquery-and-thickbox-to-wordpress-theme/41087#41087) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, toscho! I didn't realize thickbox was build in. I am having another issue and I may be trying to do something that you cannot do. When the link with thumbnail is clicked I want lightbox to show all image attachments in a post, but the function I have is nesting anchor elements within an anchor element which I know is invalid HTML. Here is the function                         `function portfolio_thumbnail_url($pid){
  $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($pid);  
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'screen-shot');  
  return  $image_url[0];  
}`

Comment: Sorry @toscho. New to stackexchange. Didn't mean to post above comment as is:-) But, not sure how to write a function that will display all post images in lightbox. Anyway, I will be using thickbox, so thanks again.

Comment: @jrelgin If my answer solved your problem tick the little checkmark on the left side so other readers know it is solved. Our list of unanswered questions is already long enough. :)